# using a subscribed return value to create subscribable promises

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

So I currently have the following code that waits for the input element to finish typing which then does an ajax.

input = input element e.g. `<input>`
axiosAjax = just my ajax

```
fromEvent(input, "keyup")
    .pipe(
        map(i => i.currentTarget.value),
        debounceTime(delay),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(value => 
        {
            this.page = 1
            return this.axiosAjax({
                path,
                method,
                data: {
                    ...data,
                    [term]: value
                }
            })
        })
    )
```

I'm trying to move the ajax out of the switchMap so that I can call an ajax outside of this function. E.g. `.subscribe( () => this.aDifferentAjax() )`. However, I'd still like to maintain the ability to discard older ajaxes.

How should I go about this?

Maybe looks something like this:

```
fromEvent(input, "keyup")
    .pipe(
        map(i => i.currentTarget.value),
        debounceTime(delay),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(value => 
        {
            this.page = 1
            return value
        })
    )
    .subscribe(
        () => this.aDifferentAjax()
        // ^This ajax can be discarded if new input is detected
    )
```

Comment: What's the problem with just wrapping `this.axiosAjax(...)` in another function and then inside `switchMap` calling that?

Comment: @martin I've actually got another function which is calling `this.axiosAjax` in the same way and I just don't want the duplicate code. I want the other function, which we'll just call `ajaxCaller`, to run each time the input is updated and to discard the previous ajax/promise. It's the discarding thing that I'm trying to work out.